# Перевод даты и времени в GMT в Python

Tags: python, datetime

проблема в чтении даты:

```
date = "20191104061459" #исходная дата

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%YYYY%m%d%f').date() # Строка перевода в дату - Ошибка, не удаётся спарсить дату.

date =time.strftime(date ,"%d.%m.%Y %I:%M %p %Z")
```

Comment: что такое %YYYY ? %Y - это и есть год, включая столетие. поменяйте %YYYY на %Y и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

date = "20191104061459"

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%f')
print(date) # 2019-11-04 00:00:00.061459
date =date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %I:%M %p %Z")
print(date) # 04.11.2019 12:00 AM
```